# How to calculate interpolated timestamps of linearly referenced points in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, interpolation, linear-referencing, timestamp, speed

I have a point feature class with timestamp attribute belongs to bus-gps smartcard data-set. I've used linear referencing tool to snap these points to a bus-route. So there are milepoints in the attribute table of points.
I have another point feature class belongs to bus-stops and i've used linear referencing tool to snap these points to the bus-route. So there are milepoints in the attribute table of bus-stops.

I've merged bus-stop points (having no timestamps) between these gps points (having no timestamps) in the same point feature class.

I need to find the timestamps of bus-stop points between gps points by interpolating according to the distance and time differences (speed) of gps points?

Is there a ready to use tool in ArcGIS toolbox? or can i calculate it in another way?

For example in the following figure, i need to interpolate timestamps of 152, 153, 154 according to the length/speed of 150 and 155.

> Simply what i want to calculate is if timestamp is T and measure is S,
>
> > T152=S152*(T155-T150)/(S155-S150)
> >
> > > Since there are lots of point features, i need to make it with a tool or script in model builder.

[image]

Comment: Look at Routes (copy your line into a route). That is what it is for. There are Web classes (old) in the training catalog.

Comment: Thank you danak but my polyline m is a route already. First i've created a route and then linearly referenced the points to this route. But some of these points'  timestamp attributes are empty. I just want to interpolate timestamps of these in-between points. On the other hand, there are some points without timestamp that in the beginning of the route and at the end of the route. These points are not in-between the points with timestamps. So these points' timestamp values need to be find by extrapolated from following or preceding points' timestamp values.